# Making a class non-copyable: Private undefined methods vs Deleted methods

Tags: c++, c++11, noncopyable

Prior to C++11, I saw code like this:

```
class Car {
public:
  Car() {}
private:
  Car(const Car&);
  Car& operator=(const Car&);
};
```

For C++11 (and later), I see code like this:

```
class Car {
public:
  Car() {}
private:
  Car(const Car&) = delete;
  Car& operator=(const Car&) = delete;
};
```

Do they behave identically?  If not, please explain.

Ref: https://ariya.io/2015/01/c-class-and-preventing-object-copy

Answer (score 5):

`=delete` will give more meaningful error messages.  An error message about a deleted function tells you that it doesn't exist and no one can create an object with said constructor.  Saying it is private doesn't give that information - it just says the caller cannot call it, not that no one can.

Also, a deleted constructor will not behave differently if called from within/outside the class (since private constructors can be called from within the class).

https://godbolt.org/g/06R9AQ

Answer (score 5):

They are similar in most respects, but differ in some others.

Consider the following *external* code trying to copy objects of the class:

```
int main() {
    Car c;
    Car other{c};
}
```

Both of these versions will cause the above code to fail. At this point, though, the developer would look at the interface to see why. With the `delete` version, it's obvious that `Car` was not meant to be copied. With the `private` version, (at least without a comment), it raises a doubt whether the copy constructor was perhaps placed in the `private` section by accident.

Now consider *member* code trying to copy objects of the class:

```
void Car::foo() {
    Car c;
    Car other{c}; 
}
```

The `delete` version fails like before. The `private` version is a link error. This raises an even greater doubt - it's not uncommon to forget to define a method that has been declared. Perhaps this is what's happened here? The `delete` version doesn't have this problem.

**Edit** Scott Meyers discusses this in Item 11 of [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) *Prefer deleted functions to private undefined ones*.

Comment: Good reference to the Scott Meyers item.  I discovered it last night.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the two snippets you posted give exactly the same error, that is something like:

> 'Car(const Car&)' is private within this context

This is because you defined the member methods as private in both cases.
If you want to appreciate the differences, you should rather have public `delete`d copy constructor and copy operator, that is:

```
class Car {
public:
  Car() {}
// private: <-- this should not be here
  Car(const Car&) = delete;
  Car& operator=(const Car&) = delete;
};
```

This way, you will be informed that those member methods have been *explicitly and intentionally deleted*:

> use of deleted function 'Car(const Car&)'

Setting them as private doesn't say explicitly *I want to delete them*.
As an example, it could have been done for you want to *force* the users of your class to use a factory method to create instances of that class.

Anyway, (no longer so) new features are not for free and using them in a way that is not the intended one won't give the expected *benefits*.

Comment: Good point about making deleted methods public for better compiler errors!

Comment: @kevinarpe Accessibility is verified before all.

Answer (score 3):

`Car& operator=(const Car&) = delete;` is expressing explicitly "copy assignment prohibited".

`= delete;` can also be used for any function as described on Bjarne's [blog](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#default):

```
struct Z {
    // ...

    Z(long long);     // can initialize with an long long
    Z(long) = delete; // but not anything less
};
```

Comment: I was not aware delete can be used for other purposes.  Excellent addition.