# (C++) What is better when making a class static: put the constructor as private or delete it publically?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I'm currently using a class which members I want to be the same across the whole program. So I need to disable the use of constructor of this class.
What is the best way of doing that ?

---

1. Declare the constructor private
2. constructor() = delete;

Comment: Use a namespace not a class.  From the question I understand that you are only using the class name for scoping, that is best done with a namespace.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of question is usually a sign that you shouldn't use a class. Unlike some other languages, not everything in C++ has to be a class, and often it shouldn't be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why explicitly delete the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654927/why-explicitly-delete-the-constructor)

Comment: Singleton pattern is a thing, so that's kind-of OK.  Make [the object non-copyable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888012/making-a-class-non-copyable-private-undefined-methods-vs-deleted-methods) and provide a public Get method for the actual static object.  My Singleton also makes the constructor private and deletes it.

Comment: The reason why I don't use a namespace is that I still want the member variables to be private, to force the use of the member functions to manage them @RichardCritten

Comment: Option 2 wasn't available in C++98 so we had to use option 1. Now we don't have to.

Comment: @AeroStun Using global variables is usually a mistake (but sometimes unavoidable). Perhaps the solution here is to make your "class" into an actual class and make the methods and private variables non-static. Explicitly passing around the object is extra work but worth it for the clarity it brings.

Comment: @AeroStun If it's header only, ok. But if you use a cpp file, you can put the variables in an anonymous namespace

Comment: I would use option `2` because it gives a better error message unless you must be compatible with pre-`C++11` in which case you have to use option `1`.

Comment: Avoid the singleton pattern... write a normal class, and if you need to use a global. There's very very few cases that justify a singleton pattern, even fewer cases than justify a global.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the Effective Modern C++ book, by Scott Meyers, Item 11: Prefer deleted functions to private undefined ones, p.74. I could give you my answer too from my perspective, but it's best you got the full picture from that chapter.

Comment: Using static classes is bad design in 99.9% cases. Use dependency injection instead (which is just a fancy word to mean passing references around). It is a much-much clearer and flexible design.

Comment: @Robinson I don't think you should put your deleted functions under the private section in your class, because C++ checks for accessibility over deleted status, and some compilers would complain without checking whether that function is deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write the code that best explains what you're doing. If you want the class to be privately constructible, make the constructor `private`. If you want nobody to be able to construct the class, then `delete` the constructor.